# Laptop screen goes black

Tags: display, lenovo-laptop

For the last month or so, my Lenovo z50 70 screen goes black when the mouse hasn't moved for 10-15 minutes.  It doesn't matter whether it is YouTube, Netflix, or just playing games with the controller, if the mouse is not moving it goes black suddenly, and when I move the mouse a bit it goes back to normal.

It looks like the screen saver, but I have turned off all of the battery saver modes and screen savers; everything is shut off.

I can't seem to find anything on Google on this specific problem so I'm in need of help.

My configuration is:

- Lenovo z50 70
- Windows 10
- Intel core i5-4210U
- 8GB RAM
- Nvidia GeForce 840M

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just confirm the screen saver is off and then check the actual settings of your selected power plan. In `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options` click `Change plan settings` and confirm that `Turn off the display` is set to `Never` There is often a different setting for mains and battery. Note that it may not be appropriate to use `Never` while running on battery, but you could set this to (say) 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I double checked everything and it's all set to never when pluged in and screen saver is off